# Transfer Godaddy Domain to Azure App Service

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service

I have a domain in Godaddy called "x.app" and I want to transfer it to Azure App Service. I have created a DNS Zone called "x.app" and I changed all the Nameservers in Godaddy:

[image]

In Azure DNS Zone, I have created a CNAME, A, TXT Records:

> A has name of @ and value of App Service IP Address
>
> CNAME has name of wildcard * and alias of App Service domain
>
> TXT has name of @ and value of App Service domain

I have added the Name of x.app as a custom domain and added a keyvault certificate:
[image]

When I just browse my domain: x.app  I receive this error:

> Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your
> information from x.app (for example, passwords, messages, or credit
> cards).

Anybody has an idea, what could cause this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a typo. According to your DNS records configuration in Azure DNS, you should add the domain `x.app` instead of `x.com` as the custom domain in the app service.

If you have done it. These errors typically originate from two things: the first is a **client-side** issue (your browser, computer, OS), and the second is that there is an actual problem with the **certificate on the website** (expired, wrong domain, not trusted by the organization). You could get more tips to fix the error [here](https://kinsta.com/blog/your-connection-is-not-private/).

For the error, you could also check **an error code message** which helps to try and pinpoint the exact issue and click the **Advanced** in Google Chrome. For example,

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID (this occurs when the certificate
>   does not match the domain)

In this case, you could upload an SSL certificate in which CN or DNS name matches the domain `x.app`. Additionally, when you bind a certificate with IP SSL, App Service creates a new, dedicated IP address for your app. You should [remap A record for IP SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings#remap-a-record-for-ip-ssl) with this dedicated IP address.

Comment: The x.com was a typo, I just edit it. I guess you are right. I tried to override the certificate check in the browser and it worked fine. As I believe now, the problem is with the certificate. I have created the certificate using Azure KeyVault Certificate generator. But I am not sure if that is the correct solution.

Comment: Do you use a self-signed SSL cert? I can reproduce your issue with a self-signed cert with Azure KV generate. The self-signed cert is not trusted by the browser and it usually used for a test environment. If you are in a production environment, suggest requesting an SSL certificate issued by a trusted CA.

Comment: Yes, I am using a self-signed SSL. I guess this is the problem. But, how can I get a certificate issued by a CA? and how much are the prices?

Comment: One more question, if I don't want to use https. what to do? I just want to be able to start the application and then deploy it into production later on. The thing is, I changed the flag of https only to off and ran the application using http, but it still 
didn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can add an SSL certificate in Azure App Service in [multiple ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate). You can get a free App Service Managed Certificate (Preview) but it does not support the nake domain in App Service or you can get a free [LetEncrypt cert](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) then import your key vault or upload your app service.

Comment: If you don't want to use HTTPS, you can remove the SSL binding. If you are in a production env, the HTTPS is more secure. If you are just testing to be able to start the application, you can ignore the warning or upload a self-signed SSL cert generated from the local machine then add this cert to the [Trusted Root Certification Authorities store for a local computer](https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Installation/Install_a_trusted_root_CA__or_self-signed_certificate). This error might  disappear on the local browser.

Comment: That is perfect and answer my question. Thank you very much for the information. I will search on this topic more. But at least, I know what the next step is.

Comment: I have now used the app service certificate service in Azure portal. It did work. Thanks for the tips again.

Comment: "If you don't want to use HTTPS, you can remove the SSL binding. " HTTPS is mandatory for any hostname under `.APP` since Google added its TLD to the HSTS preloading list, no browsers will do HTTP requests on `.app` websites.

Comment: @SamySammour "The x.com was a typo, I just edit it." Exactly one of the reason why you shouldn't obfuscate names, especially when done badly. If you really need to do that, look at RFC2606. TL;DR: use `example.com`, not any other arbitrary name.